# How to figure out which IP was used when someone logged in via ssh?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to figure out which IP was being used in the `ssh` command by an attacker attempting to ssh into a machine (although he/she failed). The machine has multiple network interfaces (multiple IP addresses) and I need to figure out which one was used by the attacker. Meaning someone did;

```
ssh root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

...and I wish to figure out what `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` was. Is this possible?

This is on CentOS 7.

Comment: You have ssh from machine A to machine B (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX). Do you want to know the IP of machine B (other than XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)? Is this a multi-homed server (several interfaces / IPs)?

Comment: I edited my question to be a bit more clear. Yes, I wish to know which IP of machine B was used since it's using multiple IP addresses (several interfaces, yes).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can find only the source IP address (attacker IP) from `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. There is no indication of destination IP address used.

I think you try iptables logging to log all IP/TCP information. You need a rule like:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG
```

This rule will log all SSH connect attempts (failed or successful). You can link this info with your audit or secure log to know the SSH login attempt result.

Answer (score 0):

sshd doesn't log such information. Unless you have some additional logging facilities in place - then not.

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect `/var/log/secure*` files.

```
grep sshd /var/log/secure*
```

**Edit**

Based on Yuri's answer, here is a little improvement.

```
grep sshd /var/log/secure* | egrep -i 'accepted|failed'
```